# Show $\mathbb{P}[X-m>\alpha]\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\alpha^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I found this problem in an old statistics book:

Suppose $X$ is a square integrable random variable  with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$. For any $\alpha>0$, show

$$
\mathbb{P}[X-m>\alpha]\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 +\alpha^2}
$$

At first I thought that the inequality results from  direct application of Markov-Chebyshev's inequality, but when I actually tried it I realized it was not so. Does anybody know about this inequality and how to obtain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is is known as Cantelli's inequality. It can be obtained from Chebyshev's but with a twist.

For any $x>0$, $\alpha+x>0$ and so,
$$ 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}[X-m>\alpha]&=\mathbf{P}[X-m+x>x+\alpha]\\
&\leq \frac{\mathbf{E}[(X-m+x)^2]}{(\alpha+x)^2}=\frac{\sigma^2+x^2}{(\alpha +x)^2}=:g(x)
\end{align}
$$

The game now is to find the *best* $x$. You can use differential Calculus  to check that $x=\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}$ does the trick.