# How to show that for any random variable $X$ and $t > 0$, $\Pr(X - E[X] \geq t\sigma[X]) \leq \frac{1}{1 + t^2}$?

Tags: probability, distribution-tails

The question in the title is from exercise 3.18 in the first edition of Mitzenmacher and Upfal's *Probability and Computing*. It's essentially asking to prove a bound slightly tighter than Chebyshev's when we only need to bound how much *larger* $X$ can be than its mean. I'm completely at a loss on how to proceed with proving it. I would appreciate a helpful hint more than an outright answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $u \ge 0$,
$$P(X-E[X] \ge t \sigma)
= P(X - E[X] + u \ge t \sigma + u)
\le \frac{E[(X-E[X]+u)^2]}{(t\sigma + u)^2}
= \frac{\sigma^2+u^2}{(t\sigma + u)^2}.$$
Choosing $u = \sigma/t$ minimizes the right-hand side with value $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$.

---

Substituting $u=\sigma/t$ in:
$$\frac{\sigma^2 + u^2}{(t\sigma + u)^2}
= \frac{\sigma^2 + \sigma^2/t^2}{(t\sigma + \sigma/t)^2}
= \frac{1+1/t^2}{(t + 1/t)^2}
= \frac{t^2 + 1}{(t^2+1)^2}
= \frac{1}{t^2 + 1}.$$

Comment: I follow your derivation, but I'm not sure what you mean by "choosing $\sigma / t$ minimizes the right-hand side with value $\frac{1}{1 + t^2}$". On substitution of this choice of $u$ into the right-hand side I don't get $\frac{1}{1 + t^2}$. Also, shouldn't the denominator in the third term of your derivation be $(t\sigma + u)^2$?

Comment: @kotu Yes the third term had a typo, now fixed. I now showed how substituting in $u=\sigma/t$ leads to $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$. The minimization is referring to choosing $u$ to minimize the function $f(u) = \frac{\sigma^2 + u^2}{(t\sigma+ u)^2}$; I omitted the justification of this.

Comment: @kotu As Oliver Diaz pointed out, my answer is the same as the proof of the more general Cantelli's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular instance of [Cantelli's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3767860/121671) that states that

> If $X$ is  square integrable random variable with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then
> $$
> \mathbb{P}[X-m>\alpha]\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 +\alpha^2}
> $$

take $\alpha=t\sigma$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what a square integrable random variable is, but the exercise in the textbook doesn't require $X$ to be a square integrable random variable. It only says that $X$ is a random variable with standard deviation $\sigma[X]$. Does having a finite standard deviation somehow imply that $X$ is a square integrable random variable?

Comment: @kotu: It means that $E[X^2]<infty$. From that it is easy to check that $E[|X|]<\infty$ so that the mean $m=E[X]$ is well defined. The variance $\sigma^2=E[(X-m)^2]=E[X^2] - (E[X])^2=E[X^2]-m^2$.

Comment: Aha! I see now why my question was marked as a duplicate. Many thanks!

Comment: @kotu: having a post marked as duplicate is not a bad thing. It just means that this question has been and answered before. If in the future you have question marked as duplicated (typically you receive a comment along the lines "Does this [link] answers your question?" I suggest you take a look at the link. If the answers there answer your questions, grand! if you don't understand the answers (it happens sometimes) respond to the message and indicate so That way others will be able to help you better.